# libx265 motion compensation and CU traverse

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, motion-detection, h.265, libx265

I'm trying to play with the H.265 motion compensation and search (HEVC- libx265 implementation from here: https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265/downloads). I need to slightly extend the edge extension search, and fill the macro block with left-most pixels as if my sample videos are like cylinder (rightmost is connected to leftmost).

What I need to do is basically this:

[image]

One way to do that is to modify the edge extension area (which is already in the code, in the `frameFilter.cpp`), and do that for rightmost and fill parts of blocks which are out with leftmost pixels. I identified the piece of code here which apparently is responsible for that. Can someone help me with implementing this feature?

```
if ((col == 0) | (col == m_frameFilter->m_numCols - 1))
    {
        // TODO: improve by process on Left or Right only
        primitives.extendRowBorder(reconPic->getLumaAddr(m_rowAddr), stride, reconPic->m_picWidth, realH, reconPic->m_lumaMarginX);

        if (m_frameFilter->m_param->internalCsp != X265_CSP_I400)
        {
            primitives.extendRowBorder(reconPic->getCbAddr(m_rowAddr), strideC, reconPic->m_picWidth >> hChromaShift, realH >> vChromaShift, reconPic->m_chromaMarginX);
            primitives.extendRowBorder(reconPic->getCrAddr(m_rowAddr), strideC, reconPic->m_picWidth >> hChromaShift, realH >> vChromaShift, reconPic->m_chromaMarginX);
        }
    }

    // Extra Left and Right border on first and last CU
    if ((col == 0) | (col == m_frameFilter->m_numCols - 1))
    {
        copySizeY += lumaMarginX;
        copySizeC += chromaMarginX;
    }

    // First column need extension left padding area and first CU
    if (col == 0)
    {
        pixY -= lumaMarginX;
        pixU -= chromaMarginX;
        pixV -= chromaMarginX;
    }
```

Comment: How is this question different than: [FFMPEG Motion Compensation and Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849595/ffmpeg-motion-compensation-and-search)?

Comment: We are a group in our class!